# Do you need to release CGContextRef in Swift?

Tags: swift, memory-management, cgcontextref

I've created a context using CGBitmapContextCreate.  Do I need to release it using CGContextRelease?  I know the answer is yes in Objective-C, but how about in Swift?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you need to follow the same rules in Swift as in Objective C

Comment: Thanks!  So does it mean that I should also release the CGImageRef?  I have the following two lines of code:

        var imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
        var image = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef)

Should I also release imageRef?

Comment: @sapi Are you sure they follow the same rules? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html

Comment: I've just written an online Swift tutorial that covers this: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/apa.html#_cftyperefs

Comment: Basically everything is memory-managed for you unless it arrives as an Unmanaged generic - and in that case, you will know because you won't be able to proceed until you add memory management.

Comment: Yes, you don't need to release it in Swift. I just added the release to my program and got a nice compiler error:

'CGContextRelease' is unavailable: Core Foundation objects are automatically memory managed

Comment: @rakeshbs My mistake; things seem to have changed since I last played with this (at which point very few API calls were annotated)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**CFTypes are automatically managed unless explicitly specified as Unmanaged.** 
 According to the documentation.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html

> Core Foundation objects returned from annotated APIs are automatically
>   memory managed in Swift—you do not need to invoke the CFRetain,
>   CFRelease, or CFAutorelease functions yourself. If you return Core
>   Foundation objects from your own C functions and Objective-C methods,
>   annotate them with either CF_RETURNS_RETAINED or
>   CF_RETURNS_NOT_RETAINED. The compiler automatically inserts memory
>   management calls when it compiles Swift code that invokes these APIs.
>   If you use only annotated APIs that do not indirectly return Core
>   Foundation objects, you can skip the rest of this section. Otherwise,
>   continue on to learn about working with unmanaged Core Foundation
>   objects.
>
> When Swift imports APIs that have not been annotated, the compiler
>   cannot automatically memory manage the returned Core Foundation
>   objects. Swift wraps these returned Core Foundation objects in an
>   Unmanaged structure.

Unmanaged types will have the type signature

```
func StringByAddingTwoStrings(CFString!, CFString!) -> Unmanaged<CFString>!
```

`CGBitmapContextCreate` has the type signature

```
func CGBitmapContextCreate(...) -> CGContext!
```

Hence its managed automatically by swift.

Answer (score 13):

No, you don't need to call `CGContextRelease`. In fact, trying to gives you this error:

> 'CGContextRelease' is unavailable: Core Foundation objects are automatically memory managed

`CGContext` instances are automatically memory managed in Swift. You can tell from the function signature:

```
func CGBitmapContextCreate(/* several parameters */) -> CGContext!
```

A return value you would need to release yourself would look like:

```
func CGBitmapContextCreate(/* several parameters */) -> Unmanaged<CGContext>!
```